# load data into table got following exception

Tags: hive, loaddata

when type "load data inpath '/group/public/aa.txt' into table managed_table;"

i got the following exception,why and how to resolve it?

```
FAILED: Hive Internal Error: java.lang.RuntimeException(java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 
does not exist: /tmp) java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does 
not exist: /tmp at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Context.getScratchDir(Context.java:148)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hive uses a temporary directory defined in `hive.exec.scratchdir` in hive-site.xml by default its `/tmp/hive-${user.name }`. I guess for some reason you don't have /tmp or don't have permissions to it.
Change the scratch dir or make it available to hive.

Comment: thanks dimamah~ when i set hive.exec.scratchdir to a hdfs dir, the load data words runs Correctly.  but why a local dir cannnot work? i got the /tmp in my system,and i can write files in it.

Comment: do you see `hive-${user.name }` directory inside /tmp? if you do, what user owns it? same user running Hive? if you don't see it, try creating it manually with the user running hive